# Para que sirve Environment SpringBoot?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Estaba haciendo unos test unitarios para ciertas funciones que ya estaban hechas y justo vi una en concreto que tiene un env.getproperty y me parecía raro porque nunca lo había visto, pero si ejecuto el test independientemente de que lo que este pasando este bien o mal, salta un error. Si pruebo en ejecutar solamente la función me indica que env esta NULL y pensé que quizás necesita el servicio estar levantado al menos en local para que funcione, pero sigue indicando error y no puedo testear.

Alguna explicación que me ayude a entender para que sirve Environment, con que propósito o porque me esta dando NULL ?

```
    @Autowired
    public Environment env;

public String validarTipoOperacion(TipoOperacion tipoOperacion, String operacion) {
    
    String respuesta = env.getProperty(tipoOperacion.toString() + "." + operacion);
    if (OK.equalsIgnoreCase(respuesta)) {
        return respuesta; 
    }
    return ("Error" + tipoOperacion.toString()+" no permitida:" + operacion);
}
```

Código del test:

```
String respuesta;
PeticionAlta peticionAlta = new PeticionAlta();
Validador validador = new Validador();


@Before
public void before() {
    peticionAlta.setTipoOperacion("alta");
    peticionAlta.setEANTitular("5901234123457");
    
}

@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    respuesta = validador.validarTipoOperacion(TipoOperacion.tipoOperacionAlta, "alta");
    assertEquals("OK",respuesta);
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir el código del test?

Comment: @PabloLozano he editado la respuesta con el código del test

Answer (score 1):

Cuando tienes un componente (una clase con anotaciones de Spring), Spring se encarga de inicializarlo: llama a su constructor e inyecta las dependencias necesarias (los atributos marcados con `@Autowired` o `@Value`, por ejemplo).

En tu test estás inicializando la clase llamando manualmente al constructor, por tanto Spring no gestiona la instancia y no inyectará nada. Es por este motivo que `env` es `null`.

¿Y qué contiene ese atributo?
Es un mapa o diccionario que guarda variables de entorno de Spring, que suelen estar definidas por ficheros `.properties` o `.yml`/`.yaml`.

Si tu proyecto tiene la clásica arquitectura de ficheros de Spring, tendrás algo como:

```
src
   main
     java
       <todo el código Java aquí>
     resources
       application.yml
       otras-propiedades.yml
   test
     java
       <todo el código de testeo aquí>
     resources
       application.yml
       otras-propiedades.yml
```

Spring usa los ficheros yml para obtener propiedades, usando en los tests los que haya en `test/resources`

Viendo tu código, se asume que en espera que se haya definido algo como:

```yml
alta:       #tipo de operacion
  alta: OK  #operacion
```

Asegúrate que en test/resources tienes una copia de esos ficheros con los valores necesarios

Y en tu test, no uses `new`, deja que Spring sea el que lance el test, configurando todo usando una de estas anotaciones:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class) // JUnit 5
```

o

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class) //JUnit 4
```

en la clase de test:

```
public class MyTest {

   @Autowired Validador validador;
   ...
```

Comment: Gracias, me ha quedado más claro para que sirve, pero si hago como tu me dices de no instanciar con new usando el Autowired y añadiendo el Extend sigue dando el error. Aunque la anotación Autowired la detecta en el fichero del test, el Extend no. Quizás estoy haciendo algo mal.

Comment: Indico el error que me ha devuelto esta vez : Cannot invoke "validadors.Validador.validarTipoOperacion(validadors.Validador$TipoOperacion, String)" because "this.validador" is null

Comment: Estás usando @JUnit 5?

Comment: Me parece que estoy usando Junit de la versión 4.12

Comment: He actualizado un poco la respuesta, a ver si así te sirve

Comment: Me da este problema de aquí org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'clientesunittest.ValidarPeticionAltaTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'validador'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:

Comment: He probado con ComponentScan algo así : @ComponentScan(basePackages = {
        "es.validators.Validator"
}) y sigue saltando

Comment: En packages no has de poner la clase, sino el package solo: `es.validators`

Comment: Lo mismo, sigue dando el mismo error

Comment: ¿La clase `Validator` tiene una anotación `@Bean` o `@Component` o algo similar? Si no es así, Spring no la va a encontrar. No sé cómo se usa en el código que va a producción, pero debería tener algo así a menos que se use manualmente (y entonces se le pase el Environment también manualmente)